# Angular extent of this composite Chandra / JWST image of the Tarantula Nebula?

Tags: observational-astronomy, photography, james-webb-space-telescope, nasa, chandra

I thought I’d ask this question here, as I couldn’t readily find the answer looking through online resources.

What is the angular extent of the composite Chandra / JWST image of the Tarantula Nebula that was released in January of 2023?

I’d like to have a rough estimate of how big this image is, relative to the entire celestial sphere.

[image]

Image source: NASA press release January 11, 2023 [Chandra/JWST Tarantula Composite Image](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/chandra/images/the-enduring-stellar-lifecycle-in-30-doradus.html)

Comment: There is a link on that page to [this page](https://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2023/30dor/), which includes the following note: "Image is about 7.24 arcmin (360 light-years) across."

Comment: Ah, so if the image is 7.24 arcmins across, with an aspect ratio of 630/1125 = 0.56, it must be 4.0544 arcmins high, with an area of ≈ 29.35 square arcmins (let’s call it 30 square arcmins). The celestial sphere’s surface area is approximately 150,000,000 square arcmins (ie, (4π steradians) • ((180/π)^2 square degrees per steradian) • (3600 square arcmins per square degree)). So, this little patch of glory is approximately 30/150,000,000 … or, one 5 millionth of the celestial sphere. Do I have that right? (Write it up, @Peter, if you’d like credit for the answer).